# Adding current word to dictionary

Tags: keyboard

I recently upgraded to Lollipop on my Nexus 5.

I use the stock keyboard for typing. Say I that while typing an email, I just typed a word that isn't in my dictionary, say `qqqwwweee`. I want to add it to the dictionary. How do I do that?

The only way I know how to do that is to type space, then backspace, then click the entry for the word above the keyboard, then "Touch here to save". These are 4 steps, and up to the fourth step you don't even know whether the word is in the dictionary or not.

Is there a **sane** way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. Lets just say, there is a word like " qpoacx ". When you type it and press space, it ll show you the word with red underline. 
Tricky part comes here.

1. Remove the space.
2. You ll get the word you are typing in the suggestions.
3. When you click on it, you ll be shown add to dictionary above the alphabets.(Not a drop down menu)

-- I ll add Screenshots in a while(in case if you didnt understand the content)